# Javascript: Is there a number data type that is 32 bit?

Tags: javascript, types

Simple Question: Javascript has dynamic variables, and it claims that the only number data type it has is the 64bit double.

I am trying to limit the amount of data I am sending over for the sake of bandwidth, so would it be possible to use 32bit floats instead? I also do not need complete precision as well, because my web app has a fast paced environment, the player wont notice if their position is 1442 instead of 1442.1415

Thanks.

Comment: Use [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: `parseInt(1442.1415)` => `1442`

Comment: If one were to convert there variable (var num = 15) to a typed array, how would one do that?

Comment: webdeb, would parsing the double into and Int really save any bandwidth? If it doesn't all it would be doing is losing precision.

Comment: Are you sending the numbers in a non-text format? IOW, four bytes instead of a string representation of a number?

Comment: I heard that socket.io automatically jsonifyies your objects that you send.

Comment: I am using socket.emit() I dont know if that automatically stringifyies or not

Comment: @webdeb No, don't do that. Use `Math.floor` for that purpose.

Comment: @Canatron You should find out what socket.io does. The JavaScript number representation is irrelevant, what matters is how that data is serialised to be sent over the wire.

Comment: Bergi do you know if socket.emit() automatically stringifies? I understand that if that were the case then it wouldn't matter how it would be stored numberically.

Comment: @Bergi whats the reason to use `Math.floor` over `parseInt` ?

Comment: gotcha https://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/55 then `Math.round()` seams even better ;)

Comment: @webdeb Performance is unimportant. The obvious reason why it's wrong is that it works on strings (and casts any numeric arguments to strings).

Comment: @Bergi you meant to integers?

Comment: @webdeb No, to strings. Which it then tries to parse as an integer.

Comment: @Bergi ah ok, that explains performance problem. thank you.

Comment: @Bergi sure, obviously, because it expects a string as the argument, so it automatically tries to cast any input to string.. damn, I did't though about that yet